# Swift 3: Why is OS_dispatch_queue_serial the default queue?

Tags: asynchronous, swift3, queue, grand-central-dispatch

When I run the following playground I notice that the **default** dispatch queue seem to be a **serial queue** called **OS_dispatch_queue_serial**.

Why is that?

In this context I am confused on the semantic usage of **async** and **sync**, as in this case they seem to be behaving both synchronously and serially.

Am I wrong? 
Am I confusing seriality with synchronisation?

[image]

Before running the code I was expecting to achieve the following:

```
Hello World
Hello Moon

world * (or Moon) 
Moon * (or world)
// Note: here I assumed that async meant that the codes in the block would have been run in parallel to each other and that this would have meant that either world or Moon would have been printed depending on **race conditions** 

Hello World
world
Hello Moon
Moon
```

**Playground** code:

```
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.test.myqueue")

queue.async {
    print("Hello World")
    sleep(2)
    print("world")
}
queue.async {
    print("Hello Moon")
    sleep(1)
    print("Moon")
}

queue.sync {
    print("Hello World")
    sleep(2)
    print("world")
}

queue.sync {
    print("Hello Moon")
    sleep(1)
    print("Moon")
}
```

Any help understanding this quicker would be great.

Answer (score 4):

You're conflating synchronous vs. asynchronous and serial vs. parallel. They're orthogonal. Let me see if I can explain it:

*Synchronous* and *asynchronous* describe the behavior of the enqueued blocks relative to the **enqueue-er**.

*Serial* and *parallel* describe the behavior of the enqueued blocks relative to **each other**.

A serial queue executes blocks enqueued to it one at a time. This is true regardless of whether the blocks were enqueued synchronously or asynchronously.

A parallel queue executes things enqueued to it N at a time, where N is possibly (but not necessarily) greater than 1. This is true regardless of whether the blocks were enqueued synchronously or asynchronously.

If you enqueue a block **synchronously**, the enqueuing thread is stopped until the block's execution is completed (possibly on another thread). This is true regardless of whether the queue is serial or parallel.

If you enqueue a block **asynchronously**, the enqueuing thread continues, and the block executes (most likely on another thread) some amount of time later, possibly while the code on the enqueuing thread is still running. This is true regardless of whether the queue is serial or parallel.

As for why serial is the default, it's hard to say, but my guess would be that it's because a 'serial queue' is more in line with the dictionary definition of the word 'queue'.

Comment: Originally (iOS 4/OS X 10.6) you couldn't create concurrent queues in GCD. There were system concurrent queues, but you couldn't create any more. In iOS 4.3/OS X 10.7 they added the ability to create concurrent queues, but kept serial queues as the default. In practice, I have only rarely found custom concurrent queues useful, usually when implementing a producer/consumer pattern (https://github.com/iosptl/ios7ptl/blob/master/ch23-AdvGCD/ProducerConsumer/ProducerConsumer/ViewController.m). The system one are usually sufficient. Usually when you make a custom queue, it's to serialize access.

Comment: (even the example I listed didn't really need a custom concurrent queue; it would have been fine with one of the system queues, so it's ever rarer than that… :D But many of the things you use a serial queue for couldn't be done without being able to make a custom one.)

Answer (score 4):

Queues come in two flavors:

- Serial - Runs blocks one at a time
- Concurrent - Runs blocks more than one at a time

Dispatching blocks to queues comes in two flavors:

- sync - Do this right now I will wait
- async - Do this later, some time.

So in your example you create a serial queue (runs only one block at a time). Then you dispatch 4 blocks to that queue. Some of them run at some point (async) and some of the run immediately (sync). But because the queue is serial you only run one of them at a time. So in the illustration below the serial queue will complete block 1 before it starts block 2. The concurrent queue starts block 1 and block 2 at the same time and they both run at the same time.

[image: Illustration of serial vs concurrent queues]

Comment: So Serial queues use FIFO and non serial queues (concurrent) use random execution criteria? (e.g. a little bit of code block 1, a little bit of code block 2..)

Comment: See the image I added. Concurrent queues do not alternate or interleave blocks 1 and 2 it executes both blocks at the same time independently.